# Highcharts add "expected" value

Tags: sqlite, highcharts

For each project there are xx requirements and for each requirement there is at least 1 team involved. Since the team is involved in this requirement, it's now expected that they create a test case later on saved as "expected". As soon as a team has created a test case, it's counted as "covered". Once I go through all requirements and check the involved teams and see if they have covered their parts and then save them to sqlite. This is done daily.

My sqlite database has the following setup:

[Sqlite setup table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiKIr.png)

This is how the current plot is:

[Plotted data on Highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2gVh.png)

The "Expected Coverage" is a sum off all the "expected" in the given date for all teams.

What I want is now to also display the expected value for each given team. Example: IOS SW Engineering: 1/**1**, TA / Certification: 0/**31**, Mechanical Engineering: 0/**9**

Is this supported in Highcharts?

Comment: Highcharts lets you graph things, if you can give it the values you want to graph, it will graph them. So if you extracted the ratio of covered to expected values from your database, you could put that in highcharts and get a graph showing you how many percents covered a given requirement is.

Comment: @ewolden this is exactly what I am looking for! Can you please show a jsfiddle example?

Comment: There is no example, what you need to do is take a value x for date, and using sqlite, or whatever languague you have on top return a value y that is covered/expected. Then you just create a series for each requirement. I would make it like so `{name: 'IOS SW Eng.', data: [{x: date, y: 0}, {x: date, y: 1}]}`

Comment: Like this; http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/ just changing snow depth to calculated covered value:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by applying custom `tooltip.formatter` function. You can find an example, that I have prepared for you below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/24fn0Lph/

Comment: This is almost what I was looking for, but I want something like this
http://imgur.com/a/OMHsQ

Where the expected value is after the covered in invidual serie

Comment: Just modify a formatter a little bit. Here is updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/mL5h3roq/.

Comment: Awesomeness. Thanks @d_paul!

Comment: a small issue here. Some of the projects don't show "Expected Coverage" even though I have the data. http://imgur.com/b4damve

Comment: Do you have 'Expected Coverage' series? If you look at my code, you will see that this is the series I created based on data from other series (line 64-67).

Comment: Nevermind. I worked it out - I noticed that I was using an older version of highcharts